# jquery('#div_id').show() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have one HTML file as shown below:

```
<html>
    <head><title>jQuery beginner</title></head>
    <body>
        <div id='my_div'>Some random generated value</div>
        <button id="submit_button">submit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to keep `<div id="my_div">` element hidden until `<button id="submit_button">` is clicked.

So in my `Javascript` file I wrote following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').hide();
});

$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    $('#my_div').show();
});
```

This script and HTML is working fine in Google Chrome and surprisingly it works in Internet Explorer 9 also but doesn't work in Firefox.

I read some other questions on SO and tried alternatives like

1. `$('#my_div').css('display','block')`,
2. `$('#my_div').css('display','inline-block')`,
3. `$('#my_div').css('display','block-table')`,
4. `$('#my_div').attr('style','display:block')`

but none of the above solution is working in Firefox.

Is there any solution to this problem?

One more thing I observed is, if I keep the div visible at page load time and later using button click event toggle it's display, it works.

Any clue why this is happening only in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you missed to try this :)

That is, wrapping the `event binding` code into the `doc ready handler`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').hide();
    $('#submit_button').click(function() {
       $('#my_div').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: oh, do I need to put button click event handler inside $(document).ready() function?

Comment: @Shekhar Yes, because element matching that selector would not be available while registering that event. :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').hide();

$('#submit_button').click(function() {
    $('#my_div').show();
});
});
```

Comment: @downvoter, C-link is right. Only downvoting doesnt help anyone. Please explain downvote.